# Playground diy or prefab

Tags: playground

Moving into our first home!  I have a 3yo daughter and an almost 2yo son. We are serious outdoors enthusiasts. I want a playground that we can play on for years.

What are the benefits or drawbacks of buying prefabricated or diy?

Comment: I don't have much to back this up, so won't make it an answer.  There are a lot of safety considerations that go into designing a good play structure that most of us wouldn't think about, so it's probably better to get at least a pro design, even if you want to build it yourself.

Comment: What level of "playground" are you thinking? A field of grass, a sandbox, a small pool and maybe a patch of strawberries and some flowers will keep kids at that age busy for years. (That's roughly what's in my garden right now and they're still loving it)

Comment: They love that stuff too! We have a large pond and lots of room to run and get dirty. My daughter is really into gymnastics so iwas thinking I can put things like a  trapeze bar, monkey bars, a climbing rope, or net, swings and a slide for baby brother.  A sandbox is also a grand idea as long as it can be covered to prevent it from becoming a large litter box

Comment: About a sandbox, we bought 2 cheap wading pools. One is the sandbox, the other is the cover--you just have to weigh the cover down.

Answer (score 2):

A combination of both DIY and pre fab would best suit you. Things like slides you may want to replace as your children grow, so I wouldn't got for anything fixed while they are small. 
Sandpits are relatively easy to construct yourself. If you have grass you can dig out a measured patch, use a weed liner in the bottom. Sleepers can be cut and screwed together for the main structure and a lid added (made of wood that's been treated or tarp). 
Monkey bars and climbing ropes are something we haven't attempted at home - this is where I'd want a professional!

Comment: Monkey bars and climbing ropes are actually one of the safer areas to DIY, as it is easy to over-engineer for strength by using bigger bolts, thicker wood etc. Many plans exist online for monkey bar/gyms suitable for adults.